# Overloading function is ambigious

Tags: c++, unit-testing, overloading, googletest

**My problem**

I have this both function headers:

```
const FlowTools::LocalFlow < double >& harmonic( const int i, const int j, const int k ) const;

const FlowTools::LocalFlow < std::complex < double > >& harmonic( const int i, const int j, const int k, const int f ) const;
```

`LocalFlow` is just a class which holds five physical parameters (velocity 3D, density and pressure). I want to **get just a double value** if there is no frequency parameter in the header. The direct component is also indicate if you are write `f=0` in the header, but in this case I get a complex value. I would not like to edit the whole program like this: xxx.harmonic().real(). Before overloading the function it calls `flowField(int i, int j, int k)`. I do refactoring.

Now I am testing the function with Google Test (unit testing library for C++) like this:

```
ASSERT_THROW(xxx.harmonic(d,d,d), ERROR);

ASSERT_THROW(xxx.harmonic(d,d,d,0), ERROR);
```

... And get this error for the first function:

> '`ASSERT_THROW( xxx.harmonic(d,d,d), ERROR)`' is ambiguous ' Candidates
>   are:
>
> `FlowTools::LocalFlow<double> & harmonic(int, int, int)`
>
> `FlowTools::LocalFlow<std::complex<double>> & harmonic(int, int, int,
>   int) '`

What is my mistake?

Comment: Indent code with four spaces (or select it then Ctrl + K).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `f = 0` so it would no longer be ambiguous.

So instead of

```
const FlowTools::LocalFlow<double>&
harmonic(int i, int j, int k) const;

const FlowTools::LocalFlow<std::complex<double>>&
harmonic(int i, int j, int k, int f = 0) const;
// f = 0 make ambiguous call when not provided
```

use

```
const FlowTools::LocalFlow<double>&
harmonic(int i, int j, int k) const;

const FlowTools::LocalFlow<std::complex<double>>&
harmonic(int i, int j, int k, int f) const;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have not define a default value f = 0. My function examples on the top show how it is implemented and there are like yours.

Comment: what do you want so see more?

Comment: @D.Mogwitz: I mean that [following](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca5a40da1f4aa304) works. So you have to provide enough code to reproduce error.